# VBA dictionary as a property of a class

Tags: vba, class, dictionary, object

I have this simplified class named clsWarehouseSum.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private wh_units As Scripting.Dictionary    

Public Function availableUnits(warehouse As String) As Long
    'Debug.Print wh_units(warehouse)
    If wh_units Is Nothing Then Set wh_units = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    If Not wh_units.Exists(warehouse) Then
    
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
        SQL = "SELECT sum(units) as tot_units " _
            & "FROM warehouse " _
            & "WHERE warehouse = '" & warehouse & "' "   
    
        Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
       
        wh_units.Add (warehouse), RS("tot_units")
        
    End If
    
    availableUnits = wh_units(warehouse)
    
    

End Function
```

I try to use it like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim wh As New clsWarehouseSum    
Debug.Print wh.availableUnits("Cohasset")
Debug.Print wh.availableUnits("Cohasset")

End Sub
```

While the first Debug.Print prints what's expected, the second one gives me an error:
`Run time error 3420, Object Invalid or no longer set.` When I step through the code, it correctly evaluates both `if` statements as `false`. Yet, the last line of the function gives me the error mentioned above. What am I doing wrong?
Why?

Comment: It works fine for me using your exact code (shortcutting the SQL to just add a 5). Edit: I also changed the dict to an Object and used `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` because I'm too lazy to add the ref.

Comment: Since the dictionary is private to the class, let the class manage its state. That means the dictionary should be instantiated in the constructor method `Class_Initialize()`, and set to nothing in the destructor method `Class_Terminate()`.

Comment: Cristian, you were right. The type was `Field3`. Why was it? Field that's being summarized is `Long`. But anyways, `CLng` function fixed the issue. Please, put it in the answer so I can reward you with correct answer

Comment: A dictionary can hold multiple types of things, so when you add  `RS(“tot units”)` you’re adding a Field object, not the Value of that field.   You need to be more explicit and use `RS(“tot units”).Value`

Comment: @user2395238 Maybe ```Field3``` is just a wrapper or even more likely, you are using late binding which causes issues with getting the correct interfaces. I deleted the comment and posted as an answer. Glad you solved it.

Comment: The error `Object Invalid or no longer set` sounds to me like when the `RS("tot_units")` would not ba a value itself, but a reference. So second time you call the `wh.availableUnits("Cohasset")` this reference is not set (as the `RS` is local variable and gets inaccessible when out of scope). So check what you actually add with `RS("tot_units")`. You need to add the `Long` value itself...which you probably know anyway :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Debug.Print TypeName(wh_units(warehouse))` before the `availableUnits = wh_units(warehouse)` line and if it prints anything else than `Long` to the *Immediate* window then you might want to cast to `Long` using `CLng` while you also have some error handler in place.

Or, you might want to make sure that the line `wh_units.Add (warehouse), RS("tot_units")` is adding a `Long` to your dictionary so you should check the type before you add.

As a general rule, when you return a specific data type from a dictionary or collection, you should always have checks in place either when you add the data to the dict/coll or when you return it so that you avoid type incompatibility and runtime errors.